# Detecting Any Object in my path using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

Can I Use Tensorflow object detection API for detecting any objects which come in between my path so that can stop the movement of my product? I have done customized Object detections before but here I can't train each object which may interrupt my product path. So is that possible to use Tensorflow API as a kind of collision detection?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With object detection, you can identify objects and the object's location and extent on an image. This would be an option to check if specific objects are blocking your path. There is also the option of detecting/segmenting unknown objects (as described [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.09127)). However, what you are after sounds more like depth estimation or even SLAM.

One example for depth estimation is [monodepth](https://github.com/nianticlabs/monodepth2) - a neural network that can estimate the depth for each pixel from a single camera image. You can use that to verify if your path is clear or if something in front of your product is blocking the path.

The other one SLAM - simultaneous location and mapping - might be a bit over the top for just checking if you can drive somewhere. Anyways, SLAM solves the task of navigating an unknown environment by building an internal model of the world and at the same time estimates the own location inside this model to solve navigation tasks.

Comment: HI,
Thanks for answering it. 

My project is simple, My product is traveling from one place to another in a straight line. but there are chances that some objects can be found in the path, if any objects are detected in my path I need to stop the moving process.

I wish to do it with TF API. The link you shared with me about detecting unknown objects doesn't contain codes wish I got a trial code.

Comment: I think depth estimation sounds like the more general approach if all you want to do is know if there is enough space in front of you. If you want to stick to TF Obj detection API then you can try the following: The obj det. model will output bounding boxes and classes and then filter the bounding boxes to output only the most fitting. You might be able to do what you want by monitoring ALL bounding box candidates and come up with some simple rules that robustly detect if there is anything in front of you. What do you think?